# How to fix wordPress Returning 404 Error?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I already kept permanent links and watched a file .htaccess ,but I still get the error. Please help me.

````
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Site-NAME/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Site-NAME/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress```
````

Comment: check your permalink setting change once and check

Comment: Not understood. I entered the admin panel. I went into permalinks and clicked save

Comment: change permalink setting change it to numeric

Comment: did not help((((

Comment: your htaccess is perfect no problem please share anything else so i can help you

Comment: I don’t know what else to share.

Comment: I solved the problem. Plugin conflict

Comment: it's nice keep working

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to disable and enable plugins. Check every time. It helped me